# How to use a slash in javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I make a Slash able to be used in this Metachar String:

```
/@(\w+)\b/gi
```

That is supposed to find the "Text"(@text) This is a test @Text I agree
And it does. But now I wan't the same thing for somthing that uses a
/

Comment: wait so includes `@` and a forward slash?

Comment: just escape it, like everything else you need that's otherwise an active character. You use `\/` inside the pattern. Just like how `\.` is a full stop, not "any character", and how `\[` is a square bracket, not a grouping operator. Hit up http://www.regular-expressions.info, too, and read up on how to use regex. The [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article doesn't start with "Search, and research" for nothing =)

Comment: Is this `/@(\w+)\b/gi` a literal you are trying to find ? Otherwise, I don't see a _Metachar String_

Comment: The only _metacharacters_ in your regex are these (+)\, the forward slashes in your string `/../` are nothing more than a delimiter, like a string delimiter. It's for the language, not the regex engine. Regex engine's don't have or know about delimiters, just metachars. Like any language string, the delimiter has to be escaped in it's contents.

Comment: Also, this RVAL form `/../` has special parsing meaning in JS, it converts it's contents into a regex _object_. It's a free-form language enhancement from long ago. New JS lets you be more specific by doing a new RegExp("") object without the `//` delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slash so it is not interpreted as denoting special meaning. Escaping means prefixing with a backslash, so you just need two together. Adapting your existing example:

```
/@([\w\/]+)\b/gi
```

You're now allowing alphanumeric and slash characters (hence the need for a "range" of characters, denoted by square brackets.)

Comment: close! I think he was talking about a forward slash though

Comment: This doesn't matches `@text/`. What is the reason ?

Comment: @RichardHamilton - thanks, edited. My inattentiveness.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do it: Try:(will match /Text)

```
/\/(\w+)\b/gi
```